# Draggable не работает с js

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Начал изучать как реализовать Drag and Drop на сайте. Создал тестовый файл и сразу же столкнулся с проблемой, когда всё говорит о том, что это должно работать, но оно не работает (должно вывести сообщение в консоли). HTML CSS и Js код прилагаю. Подскажите что может быть не так?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <ul class="tasks__list">
    <li class="draggable" draggable="true">learn HTML</li>
    <li class="draggable" draggable="true">learn CSS</li>
    <li class="draggable" draggable="true">learn JavaScript</li>
  </ul>
   <div class="ans-s">
        <div class="answer"></div>
       <div class="answer"></div>
       <div class="answer"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (просто чтобыб был, в этом вопросе он роли не играет):

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
.tasks__list,
.ans-s{
    top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

.ans-s{
    right: 150px;
}
.tasks__list{
    left: 150px;
}

.answer, 
.draggable{
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin-left: 45px;
}

.answer{
    background-color: forestgreen;
}

.draggable{
    background-color: crimson;
}

.selected{
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

И Js, в котором скорее всего и проблема:

```
const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".tasks__list");

draggables.forEach((draggable) => {
    draggable.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
        console.log("Dragging !!! Wow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Скорее всего, ваш скрипт отрабатывает быстрее, чем создается DOM. Попробуйте обернуть код в функцию и вызвать ее в onload тега body

Comment: Посмотрите [вот этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1451380/%d0%a3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2), там есть пример, как это сделать

Comment: @SwaD Спасибо большое! Ты был прав, всё оказалось так очевидно) Хотя я уже пытался обернуть это всё в функцию и вызвать в теге script внутри body, но это не работало. А через onLoad сработало)